# What's a good character to separate strings with leading white-spaces?

Tags: string, perl, whitespace, separator, null-character

I'm using the null character (`\0`) as a separator to keep the strings leading white-spaces after the `sprintf`. But the strings with the null character don't work (in this case) with the `Curses` `addstr` function.
Is there some suitable character to replace the `\0` for this purpose?

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use 5.12.0;


sub routine {
    my @list = @_;
    @list = map{ "\0".$_."\0"; } @list;
    # ...
    # ...
    @list = map{ sprintf "%35.35s", $_ } @list;
    # ...
    # ...
    my $result = $list[5];

    $result =~ s/\A\s+\0//;
    $result =~ s/\0\s+\z//;
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you doing that is stripping whitespace? `sprintf`?

Comment: I think you should be using [substr](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/substr.html) instead of `sprintf`.

Comment: This is an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=XY%20Problem). What is `routine` actually trying to do?

Comment: There was an error in the example. I map the list through `sprintf`, so all items have the same length (longest item). (to get a nice output). But now I am considering to use `printf` at the end when printing to the screen, so I don't need a separation character. I didn't do that until now, because I thought `printf` would be slower than `print` but maybe there is no big difference.

Answer (score 0):

What about using some pretty print module from CPAN?

http://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Format::Pretty::Console

http://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Tabulate

Comment: I need to move around on the screen (similar to the `choose` function from [Term::Clui](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Term::Clui)).